# Windows authentication works fine in IE but not in Edge chromium

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I use windows authentication to get user information using below function. This functions works fine in IE.When I use visual studio and run in Edge windows authentication window keeps on pop up

These are the function I use to get user name. This is not working in local host even after enabling windows authentication.
Request.ServerVariables("Auth_User");
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

Please let me know if there are any other function which can be used to get logged in user name.

Comment: What's the authentication mode in web.config?

Comment: <authentication mode="Windows"/> @stark